# How to program regex to include space in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex, which is suppose to validate strings like `R1 AND R2` or `R1 AND R3 OR R2 AND R4`.

This is my regex:

```
^[R\d+ (\bAND\b|\bOR\b)]+ R\d+$
```

Today, I found out that it also accepts strings like "R1AND R2" or "R1 ANDR R2". How can I make sure that my regex must detect spaces between the R\d, AND and OR?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a character class, it's wrong, use a non capture group instead:

```
^(?:R\d+\s(?:AND|OR)\s+)*R\d+$
```

Comment: If you want to explicitly only allow the space character and not all white spaces, use `\x20` instead of `\s`.

Answer (score 1):

```
^R\d+(?:\s+(?:AND|OR)\s+R\d+)*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rU8yP6/4

The reaosn yours is not working is because you have included evrything inside `[]` character class which does not maintian sequence and is just a pool of characters to chose from.

This will match `R1 AND R3 OR R2 AND R4` and `R1 AND R3` but not `R1AND R3`

Comment: Nice grouping :) Thanks!